# How to count sub data of customer in SQL

Tags: sql

I have Customer table as following

```
CustomerId     CustomerName   CustomerEmail
1              AAA            AAA@AAA.com
2              BBB            BBB@BBB.BBB
```

This is example data I have shown. Like this I have 50000 customer in `customer` table now their invoices are also stored in `invoice` table

```
InvoiceId      InvoiceAmount   InvoiceCustomerID
1              22.00           1
2              58.00           2
3              21.00           2
4              45.00           2
```

Now I want to count the invoice for each customer when I show the customer listing, for example:

```
CustomerId     CustomerName   CustomerEmail  TotalInvoice
1              AAA            AAA@AAA.com    1
2              BBB            BBB@BBB.BBB    3
```

I have used the following query but didnt worked

```
SELECT customer.*,COUNT(invoice.InvoiceId) FROM `customer` as customer INNER JOIN invoice as invoice ON customer.CustomerId= invoice.InvoiceCustomerID
```

Can suggest any method to solve this ?

Also there is more then 5 lacks invoice so it's taking to much time to load.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, a.CustomerName, a.CustomerEmail,
SUM(CASE WHEN b.InvoiceID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalInvoice
FROM `customer` a LEFT JOIN invoice b ON a.CustomerId= b.InvoiceCustomerID
GROUP BY a.CustomerId, a.CustomerName, a.CustomerEmail
```

Just use `GROUP BY`
Also, do you need to display customers with no invoices? You're going to have to turn this into a left join if you do.

Comment: Why not COUNT(invoice.InvoiceId) instead of sum/case?

Comment: I guess count also works; was just much more used to using sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a grouping function without GROUP BY:

```
SELECT customer.CustomerID, customer.Customer.Name, customer.CustomerEmail
    ,COUNT(invoice.InvoiceId) AS RC
FROM `customer` AS customer
INNER JOIN invoice AS invoice ON customer.CustomerId = invoice.InvoiceCustomerID
GROUP BY  customer.CustomerID, customer.Customer.Name, customer.CustomerEmail
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.CustomerId "CustomerId", 
c.CustomerName "CustomerName", 
c.CustomerEmail "CustomerEmail", 
count(i.InvoiceCustomerID) "TotalInvoice"  
from customer as c 
inner join invocie i 
on(i.InvoiceCustomerID = c.CustomerId) group by
c.CustomerId, c.CustomerName, c.CustomerEmail order by CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

due to bulk data other queries was taking to much time to load

so I have settled the issue using following query

```
SELECT c.CustomerId,c.CustomerName,totalinvoice AS ttlinv FROM customer 
as c LEFT JOIN (select COUNT(InvoiceId) as totalinvoice,InvoiceCustomerID 
from invoice GROUP by InvoiceCustomerID) as io on io.InvoiceCustomerID=c.CustomerId
```